# How does my code work, I can't understand the flow?

Tags: c, loops, while-loop

I can't understand why the output = 8 if a=16 b=24

```
int a,b,t;
scanf("%d %d", &a , &b);
while(b){
    t = a%b;
    a = b;
    b = t;
}
printf("%d\n", a);
```

Comment: Do you know how to use a debugger? If not, at least put `printf` statements in your loop to print out intermediate values of the variables.

Comment: What do you expect it to be?

Comment: Use a `printf("%d %d %d\n", t, a, b)` In the beginning and end of the loop to see what happens.. But make sure to initialize t to something.

Comment: You cannot completely change the question after people already commented/answered. If you have something different to ask, create a new question.

Comment: If it's your code, how come you don't understand what it does?  It's better not to claim code that you don't understand as being your own.

Answer (score 5):

This is just implementing [Euclid's Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm) for GCD.  It just takes the remainder of one value vs. the other, using that as a new value and shifting the other down.  So you have:

```
    a    b
   16   24
   24   16
   16    8
    8    0
```

The algorithm ends when `b` reaches `0`, at which point `a` holds the GCD value.

Answer (score 2):

```
                        //   a  b  t
while(b){               //  16 24
    t = a%b;            //  16 24 16
    a = b;              //  24 24 16
    b = t;              //  24 16 16
}
while(b){               //  24 16 16
    t = a%b;            //  24 16  8
    a = b;              //  16 16  8
    b = t;              //  16  8  8
}
while(b){               //  16  8  8
    t = a%b;            //  16  8  0
    a = b;              //   8  8  0
    b = t;              //   8  0  0
}
while(b){               //   8  0  0
}
printf("%d\n", a);      //   8  0  0
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to understand this, you might temporarily change your code into the following:

```
int a,b,t;
scanf("%d %d", &a , &b);
while(b){
    printf("Comment: the beginning of  while-loop, a=[%d], b=[%d], t=[%d]", a, b, t);
    t = a%b;
    printf("Comment: after the modulo calculation, a=[%d], b=[%d], t=[%d]", a, b, t);
    a = b;
    printf("Comment: after assigning b to a,       a=[%d], b=[%d], t=[%d]", a, b, t);
    b = t;
    printf("Comment: after assigning t to b,       a=[%d], b=[%d], t=[%d]", a, b, t);
}
printf("%d\n", a);
```

This will print out all values you are interested in and you'll better understand what's happening. Once you've understood how it all works, you can decide, either to remove those extra lines, either to put them in comment (in case you might need it again later).